# how to find the selected value and text of multiple select boxes and add them to hidden fields

Tags: jquery

I've been stuck with this problem for sometime now, I just don't seem to find a way to fix it.I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me.

I have multiple select boxes on 1 page, I need to get the text of the select boxes(which is the qty of an item) and the value of the selectboxes (the price of the item) and the item description which is in a span tag with a class descriptionColor,

and when someone chooses something from the first select box and sth from the second and so on,I need to add the item name, quantity and total price of each item to hidden fields.

so the hidden field would include:
for name:qty of item 1 + item1 name,qty of item2 + item2 name ...
for price:total price of all items.

```
 <td><span class="descriptions"><span class="descriptionsColor">MIXED SALAD</span></span></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="body">

        <select class="select" name="select3" id="select3">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1.99">1</option>
          <option value="1.99">2</option>
          <option value="1.99">3</option>
          <option value="1.99">4</option>
          <option value="1.99">5</option>
          <option value="1.99">6</option>
          <option value="1.99">7</option>
          <option value="1.99">8</option>
        </select>

        </td>

     <td><span class="descriptions"><span class="descriptionsColor">ONION RINGS</span></span></td>
        <td class="body">10 Pieces</td>
        <td><span class="body">
          <select  class="select" name="select" id="select">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1.99">1</option>
            <option value="1.99">2</option>
            <option value="1.99">3</option>
            <option value="1.99">4</option>
            <option value="1.99">5</option>
            <option value="1.99">6</option>
            <option value="1.99">7</option>
            <option value="1.99">8</option>
          </select>
        </span></td>
          ..
          ..

$(function () {
   $('#my-add-button-sides').click(function() {

    var qty = [];
    var price = [];
    var items = [];
    $('.select').children('option :selected').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        qty.push($this.text() );
        price.push($this.val() );
        items.push( ($(this).prevAll(".descriptionsColor").text()) );
    });

    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9000)+200);
    $('input[name=my-item-id]').val(randomNumber);
    $('input[name=my-item-name]').val(items);
    $('input[name=my-item-price]').val(price * qty);


 });
});
```

Comment: Have you not already asked the same question multiple times with a slightly different angle. Surely you can pull together all the answers you have already had into one solution that works. Either learn to learn or hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: I just don't understand why the above solution doesn't work.
It looks but it gives incorrect answers.

Comment: I meant to say it seems ok but it's not working.

Comment: it just feels like you are using us and multiple questions to try and pull together a whole solution without even trying to understand anything. Check your previous questions

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tableid").find(".select").each(funcion(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```